# Fail to Launch the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant

I tried to Launch rails server on vagrant but I can't.
The error message is here.

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I did `bundle install` but...

```
An error occurred while installing sassc (2.3.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install sassc -v '2.3.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

then I did

$ gem install sassc -v '2.3.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'

the message is

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sassc:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.3.0/ext
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200422-11227-g7m1en.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.3.0/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.3.0/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ./libsass/src/ast.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [ast.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sassc-2.3.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/sassc-2.3.0/gem_make.out
```

then I did "$ rails server -b 192.168.33.10 -d"

but

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

The result is same...

What should I do next?

Comment: Are your dev tools up to date? Recent versions of gcc and C++ stdlib?

Comment: Here is my version 

[vagrant@localhost myapp]$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: [_GCC 4.8.1 was the first feature-complete implementation of the 2011 C++ standard_](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), so time to upgrade.